# Unable to fetch data from database in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Once the user login into site unable to fetch the data from database getting blank page if i write foreach condition here is my code.Fetching username and login verification is workig fine.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')){
$data['admin_details'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
$data['records']= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->uri->segment(3));
$data['mainpage']='profile';
$this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
else{

    $this->load->view('welcome');
}
}
```

Model:

```
function getprofiledata($id)
{
    $this->db->select('profile_details.*');     
    $this->db->from('profile_details');     
    $this->db->where(array('profile_details.profile_id'=>$id));     
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    return $q->result();
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div id="legend">
    <legend class="">Profile Information</legend>
</div>   
<?php if(isset($records) && is_array($records) && count($records)>0): ?>
            <?php foreach($records as $r):?>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>profile/updateprofile" role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="location" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <?php
        echo form_hidden('profile_id',$r->profile_id);
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="name">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php echo $r->first_name;?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="profilename">Profile Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profile_name" placeholder="Enter Profile name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="designation">Designation:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation" placeholder="Enter Designation">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php endforeach;endif;?>
```

Comment: Well for starters I would do a var_dump($data) just before you load the view and inspect things are what you expect them to be.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw not gettig what you are saying

Comment: `$records= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->uri->segment(3));
$data['records']= $records;
var_dump($record);` and then show `var_dump` result

Comment: @razibalmamun getting error as undefined variable records and getting blank page

Comment: where you checked `var_dump` ? and are you sure properly you are getting profile id in `$this->uri->segment(3)` ? let me know

Comment: @razibalmamun $data['records']= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->uri->segment(3));
 $data['records']=$records;
 var_dump($records);

Comment: Please use this carefully and let me know `$records = $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->uri->segment(3))‌​; 
var_dump($record); 
$data['records']= $records;`

Comment: @razibalmamun not sure how to check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127102/discussion-between-razibalmamun-and-user7047368).

Comment: @razibalmamun Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​‌​' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\application\controllers\profile.php on line 28

Comment: ok, you can just in your index method `var_dump($this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->uri->segment(3)))` and let me know this result

Comment: echo $this->uri->segment(3); inside your controller. Is it what you expect? If it's not, you get no record from db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose the wrong segment number on line `$data['records']= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->uri->segment(3));`.

Take notice that segment counting starts with zero, so segment no 3 is actually the 4th one in the uri.

If you keep the user id inside your session, you should replace `$data['records']= $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->uri->segment(3));` with `$records = $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($this->session->userdata('profile_id'))‌​‌​‌​;`. And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

add a new session when you login process like bellow in your login model :

```
<?php
public function login_user($user_name = '', $password=''){ 
    $userdetails = array( 
    'email' => $user_name, 
    'password' => md5($password), 
    'status'=>1,     
    ); 

    $this->db->where($userdetails); 
    $query = $this->db->get('profile_details');  

    if($query->num_rows()): 
        $user = $query->result(); 
        $sess_arry = array( 
            'profile_id' => $user[0]->profile_id, // add new session profile_id
            'first_name' => $user[0]->first_name 
        );  
        $this->session->set_userdata('admin_logged_in', $sess_arry);    //add admin details to session   
        return true; 
    else: 
        return false; 
    endif; 
}
?>
```

And some change your `index` method like bellow :

```
<?php
public function index() 
{ 
    if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')){ 
        $data['admin_details'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in'); 
        $data['country'] = $this->signup_model->getcountry();   
        $data['states'] = $this->profile_model->getstates();

        $profile_id = $this->session->userdata('profile_id');
        $records = $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($profile_id)‌​‌​;

        $data['records']= $records; 

        $data['mainpage']='profile'; 
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data); 
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar',$data); 
    } 
    else{ 
        $this->load->view('welcome'); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

I have added new 3 line because i thinks you are no getting profile id properly in  `$this->uri->segment(3)`

So,

```
$profile_id = $this->session->userdata('profile_id');
$records = $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($profile_id)‌​‌​; 

$data['records']= $records;
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. `$records = $this->profile_model->getprofiledata($profile_id)‌​‌​;` copy this line and paste your page, and let me know